# ı can't use variables in MySQL commands

Tags: mysql, sql

`set @tmpGuid = REPLACE( uuid(),'-',''); set @fieldName = concat('deneme' , '_' , @tmpGuid); ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN deneme to @fieldName;`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciQ44.png

how can use my variable on mysql commands

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL

Comment: MySQL does not support variables in Data Definition Language (ie statements defining the data structure).

Answer (score 0):

Many DBMS don't allow DDL statements to be parameterised. I.e. alter, create statements and such.

However this doesn't mean it's impossible. What you'd need to do is convert your statement to dynamic SQL, which you can manipulate in every way possible (including inserting parameters into the string).
Then simply executing it.

In your example:

```
SET @tmpGuid = REPLACE( uuid(),'-',''); 
SET @fieldName = concat('deneme' , '_' , @tmpGuid); 

SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN deneme to ', @fieldName);

PREPARE dynamic_SQL FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_SQL;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_SQL;
```

Ofcourse using dynamic SQL has it's own troubles, and opens up potential risks. But it's the only way to do something like this.

See it in action: [Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/TwMBcpep5LZ8vPVDnjKGa/0)

Answer (score 0):

Variables are meant to store data, not code. In SQL, table and column names count as the latter. From [User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html):

> User variables are intended to provide data values. They cannot be used directly in an SQL statement as an identifier or as part of an identifier, such as in contexts where a table or database name is expected, or as a reserved word such as `SELECT`.

Comment: While correct in the intended use of variables, it doesn't mean it's impossible. Though you should always question your useage. And sometimes it's the only way to accomplish/automate something that for instance you apply to every single database on a server.

Comment: @DKramer It isn't possible in SQL just like it isn't possible in many other languages. Your own answer follows a different path.